# font-family crash with @font-face src

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

Good day,

I have a css, code is as follow:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot');
}

body {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
}
```

And, in my html code, I simply code:

```
<b>this is bold</b> + this is normal
```

And this is display correctly in chrome, but not in IE (All become normal, not bold).

If I remove the `body{}` in my css file, then IE will working fine.
If I remove either `font-family` or `src` inside @font-face, then IE will working fine.

I do some research on internet, found that `.eot` file will not support for chrome, that's why chrome wont affected and display correctly. (Not sure my understanding is correct or not)

Kindly advise. And suggest your solution if you have.

** Edit **

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot'); 
    src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.svg#dax-regularregular') format('svg'),
         url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

** Edit version 2 **
This solution can fix IE 9, IE 10, and IE 11 issue. But, 
This solution introduce new issue to IE 8,  which is , normal word will be bold, and the bold word will become "more bold" ( become fatter ). I saw from internet, IE 8 is not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format). So, i take out those url except eot, but still facing the problem.

I change my css code to as follow, but still same hit issue in IE 8:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I've just had a similar behaviour with a different format.  Working in Firefox and chrome but it defaults to default font. I switched to another font with a supported type, and it worked

Comment: i think you have to laod `.woff` also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code shows that you have included only `.eot` format webfont in body in css. The `.eot` format will work only on IE.

Now since you have added only `url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot')` [notice 'regular'], the IE browser showing your text in regular or not-in-bold format. So if you want to display your text in-bold format on IE, you would need to add an additional `url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot')` [notice 'bold'] definition in your css and also the relevant font in your font folder.

Now, why chrome displays it properly? I doubt if chrome would be showing your text in your desired font i.e. `dax` or `.eot`. Since you have not defined `.woff` font in your css (which chrome normally requires), most probably using some other font defined in some other css on your page.

To display your page consistently across all browsers using for custom font you would need to add all fonts definition in your css including adding the same in your font folder -

```
`@font-face {
  font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
  src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}`
```

---

**UPDATE:**

First, other then font definition mentioned above you'll also have to add other font formats definitions in your css like

for bold,

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'dax-bold';
      src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot');
      src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
           url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

for semibold,

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'dax-semibold';
      src: url('../fonts/daxsemibold-webfont.eot');
      src: url('../fonts/daxsemibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
           url('../fonts/daxsemibold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
           url('../fonts/daxsemibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
           url('../fonts/daxsemibold-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
           url('../fonts/daxsemibold-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
    }
```

and so on including relevant fonts in font folder, whichever you need.

Second, for getting these fonts. Not sure but I think your `dax` font seems a licensed font and not the free one. If yes, then you can convert all above mentioned formats using the `ttf / otf` font which would have been installed in your system's 'Font' folder. To convert just copy the 'regular' or 'bold' font from that font folder on your desktop and then convert it using website like ['Font Squirrel'](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

**UPDATE 2**

1. The IE needs `.eot` version web-font only, having `.woff` won't affect text in any IE version. So don't fear of `.woff`.
2. You need to correct your font definition, which is still incorrect in your last post -

for regular or unbold font,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

for bold format font,

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-bold';
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
}
```

Your html should look like this -

```
<p style="font-family: 'dax-regularregular';"><span style="font-family: 'dax-bold';">bold text lying here</span> unbold text lying here</p>
```

It should work proper across.

*Note: Have shown applying font in inline  tag to demonstrate html structure, please use your class for the same.*

Comment: Just change my code, in ** edit ** portion,  according to what you mention, but still same. Can help review again?

Comment: Did you also add the said `.woff` `.svg` `.ttf` fonts in your font folder, where `.eot` font is also lying? Also check once clearing cache.

Comment: Yes. Added except "daxbold-webfont.eot", this is my mistake. May I know where can I download those eot file, I have those eot file because is commit by previous developer, now the developer no longer here. Ya, sure I clearing cache everything i test.

Comment: please check my UPDATE above in my reply.

Comment: Get what you means at first part. But a bit confuse in second part which is how to getting these fonts file. Sorry ask you a silly question, In my workspace I have those `daxregular-webfont.eot`, `.woff`, `.ttf`, `.svg` files. and another file is `DaxRegular.ttf`. So you means I need to upload this `DaxRegular.ttf` to the website u meantion, and click `DOWNLOAD YOUR KIT` button, then I can get those daxbold eot file and so on?

Comment: You must have 'DaxBold.ttf' file to get web-fonts for this format. Regular will generate only for regular.

Comment: Hi Ravi. This solution solve IE 9, IE 10 and IE 11 issue. But introduce new issue to IE 8, which is , normal word will be bold, and the bold word will become "more bold" ( become fatter ). I saw from internet, IE 8 is not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format). So, i take out those url except eot, but still facing the problem. Do u have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your bold format text inside `<b>...</b>` tag and also having applying bold font family on it or its parent element. If so try putting your bold format text in `<span>` instead `<b>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I have put my text inside `<b></b>` tag for the text that I want to bold. For the normal text, I didnt put inside `<b></b>` . But the problem is text inside `<b></b>` will become "more bold", and normal text will become bold. Btw, I already edit my question in ** Edit version 2 **, my font-family still `dax-regularregular`, u means I need to change to other font family?

Comment: check UPDATE 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding different types of fonts and specifying there type as well..

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
  src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: Done. But still the same. Maybe u can help me to review again.

Answer (score 0):

Add more font file like

```
font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
src: url('dax-regularregular.eot');
src: url('dax-regularregular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('dax-regularregular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('dax-regularregular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('dax-regularregular.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
```

**Generate your font blow link**

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator