# @font-face fix in IE 9 and above but introduce new issue in IE 8

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

Good day,

Initially, I have a `font-face` and its working fine in all browser except IE 9 and above:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/daxregular-webfont.svg#dax-regularregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

To fix this, I add in another `font-face`:

```
/* To fix IE 9 and above bold issue */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.svg#dax-regularregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This fix my issue in IE 9 and above, however, it introduce new issue in IE 8. Which is, normal word will be bold, and the bold word will become "more bold" ( become fatter ). I saw from internet, IE 8 is not support the @font-face rule with the WOFF format (only support for EOT format). So, i take out those url except eot, but still facing the problem.

I change my css code to as follow, but still same hit issue in IE 8:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'dax-regularregular';
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/daxbold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: bold;
}
```

My original question is [font-family crash with @font-face src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323693/font-family-crash-with-font-face-src)

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
    src: url('myfont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('myfont-webfont.woff') format('woff'), 
        url('myfont-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'),
        url('myfont-webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
}
```